# On react-native-video, how can I manually adjust the video quality across all platforms?

Tags: react-native, video, react-native-video

I'm creating a react-native app that uses react-native-video to stream video. I want users to be able to manually modify the video quality. I haven't been able to figure out how to accomplish it up until now.
Please give your suggestions on how to implement!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The equation does not require any code example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most reasonable way to overcome this problem is to use a video streaming service. react-native-video component cannot solve this problem by itself. Video streaming services encode source video to different qualities. For example, let your source video file be 1080p. The video streaming service will encode and store your video into 720p, 480p, 360p quality options, then you can choose one of these qualities according to the user's request or internet speed. You should do some research about video streaming services(AWS, BunnyCDN etc.) and video streaming documentation.